# Error with PHP - Humhub

Tags: php, sql, localhost, humhub

thank you for your attention.
I'm trying to install an open source social networking system ( Humhub https://www.humhub.org/en ) on my xampp, but I'm having the following error in php:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\humhub/protected/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\humhub\index.php on line 13
```

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\humhub/protected/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\humhub\index.php on line 13

Comment: Does that product have installation instructions? It feels that it expects you to install Composer dependencies but you haven't.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't think that it need composer, because it is available only as downloadable package on its official website.

Comment: What is the version of PHP that your XAMPP ruining?

Comment: Yes, it has documentation. I followed every step: http://docs.humhub.org/index.html

Comment: @SaidbakR My PHP version is 7.2.0

Comment: Does the `autoload.php` file exist at the location above?

Comment: @AdamHopkinson yes, all files are in the httdocs folder.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you edit `include_path` in your `php.ini` file to include current directory (`.`)? I don't think it should but the issue is already weird enough so...

Answer (score 0):

You have followed the developer instruction to setup as at:
https://docs.humhub.org/docs/develop/environment

If you run `composer install` then it will generate the autoload.php

Else to skip all that, just download and install from:
https://www.humhub.com/en/download